# Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, root

I know that there are a lot of questions of this problem but I cannot resolve my problem with the other posts.

I don't understand why I see this message.

**MainActivity**

```
alert = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView iv_foto;
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        iv_foto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_foto);



    }

    public void sacarFoto(View v){
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }


    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.josemiguelrodriguez.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO){
            iv_foto.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.josemiguelrodriguez.pruebacamara">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true"
        />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.josemiguelrodriguez.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**file_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-file-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```

**Error:**

```
03-31 13:39:14.292 30787-30787/com.example.josemiguelrodriguez.pruebacamara E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.josemiguelrodriguez.pruebacamara, PID: 30787
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.josemiguelrodriguez.pruebacamara/files/Pictures/JPEG_20170331_133914_-2001489715.jpg
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
at com.example.josemiguelrodriguez.pruebacamara.MainActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(MainActivity.java:67)
at com.example.josemiguelrodriguez.pruebacamara.MainActivity.sacarFoto(MainActivity.java:33)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Many Thanks!! :D

**UPDATE**
The error is solved with the first response of @CommonsWare but now I have the following error:

**Error**

```
resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.josemiguelrodri‌​guez.pruebacamara/fi‌​les/Pictures/JPEG_20‌​170331_140455_-20014‌​89715.png
```

Comment: `photoFile = createImageFile();`. You should not create the file your self. Leave that to the camera app. You should only care for a file name.

Comment: `".jpg",         /* suffix */` AND `JPEG_20‌​170331_140455_-20014‌​89715.png ` do not match.

Comment: @greenapps
I have been changed the line ".jpg" by ".png" and the error is the same.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

in file_paths.xml as it's asking for root.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <root-path name="root" path="." />
    </paths>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `external-file-path` to `external-files-path` (note the `s`).

Comment: Many thanks, the error is resolved, but now I see this error:

 resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.josemiguelrodriguez.pruebacamara/files/Pictures/JPEG_20170331_140455_-2001489715.png

Comment: @JMR: You need to add `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` to your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent` for the other app to be able to save a photo in your `FileProvider`. See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider

Comment: Thanks, I have been added the FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION but the error is the same...

Comment: Is there any things new? Thanks you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Change to

```
File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

And/Or change `path="Pictures"` to `path="."`.

Comment: I cannot to do that, because I want to save in the file directory of my app. Thanks.

Comment: Change path="Pictures" to path=".".

Comment: The problem is resolv with the before answer, but now I have this error: 

resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.josemiguelrodri‌​guez.pruebacamara/fi‌​les/Pictures/JPEG_20‌​170331_140455_-20014‌​89715.png

Thanks

Comment: when I take the photo start the error.

Many thanks.

Comment: when I call to photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"com.example.josemiguelrodriguez.fileprovider",file);

I see the following eror: 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.josemiguelrodriguez.pruebacamara/files/images/JPEG_20170404_1320331525042017.jpg

Thanks

Comment: `configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.josemiguelrodriguez.pruebacamara/file‌​s/images/JPEG_201704‌​04_1320331525042017.‌​jpg`. ??? That is an internal private path. Imposstble that you get such an error using getExternalFilesDir() as you do in your code.

Comment: Can you please stop with your 'Thanks'!

Comment: No, I see the error when I call to FileProvider.getUriForFile.